# How to get directory listing in Next.js on Netlify

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, netlify

I have a problem to get a directory listing in Next.js on Netlify. It works well on **localhost**, but when I deploy the site to Netlify I get this error:

```
{
"errorType": "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection",
"errorMessage": "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/opt/build/repo/storage/videos/'",
"trace": [
"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/opt/build/repo/storage/videos/'",
"    at process.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:35:15)",
"    at process.emit (events.js:314:20)",
"    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:209:33)",
"    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:98:32)"
]
}
```

This is my `next.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    serverRuntimeConfig: {
        PROJECT_ROOT: __dirname
    },
    target: 'experimental-serverless-trace'
};
```

This is my `pages/index.js`:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import { project_root } from '@config/app';

...

export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const videosPath = path.join(project_root, './storage/videos/');

    fs.readdirSync(videosPath).forEach(video => {
        // Do stuff with a path...
    });

    ...
}
```

And this is `config/app.js`:

```
import getConfig from 'next/config';

const { serverRuntimeConfig } = getConfig();

export const project_root = serverRuntimeConfig.PROJECT_ROOT;
```

I'm new to both Next.js and Netlify, so I'm not sure what is the problem. I see that path `/opt/build/repo/storage/videos/` which is `readdirSync` reading is invalid and probably should be like `var/runtime/storage/videos/`, but I don't know how to fix it and make it work on both Netlify and localhost.

PS: Yes, I do have files in the `storage/videos` folder as well as on git, and on Netlify I installed these plugins for the project:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem an I fixed by validating If the directory exist, If not, create a directory:

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const videosPath = path.join(project_root, './storage/videos/');

    if (fs?.existsSync(videosPath)) { // Validate if directory exist
        return fs.readdirSync(videosPath).forEach(video => {
            // Do stuff with a path...
        });
    } else { // If not exist create a directory
        return fs?.mkdirSync(videosPath, { recursive: true });
    }

    ...
}
```